# Smart-Table - Preselect a specific row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, smart-table

I'm using smart-table and I need to preselect a specific row.

So after loading my list, I loop into it and set the `isSelected` attribute when I reach the item I want to select:

```
// Preselect a row
for (var i = 0, len = scope.displayCollection.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    var person = scope.displayCollection[i];
    if (person.firstName === 'Blandine') {
        person.isSelected = true;
        scope.selected = person;
        break;
    }
}
```

It's working fine, but when I want to select another line, the preselected line is not unselected! I have to click on it to manually unselect it and then be able to select another line correctly.

Here is a JSFiddle explaining the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/6pykn5hu/3/

I tried what's proposed there [Smart-Table - Select first row displayed (angularjs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29193530/smart-table-select-first-row-displayed-angularjs) but did not manage to have someting working.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I looked through their [directive](https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/blob/master/src/stSelectRow.js) as you can see it calls a function in a parent directive `stTable`. The `row` is bound to a click handler...Which calls the `ctrl.select()` function from `stTable` this function in turn stores the last selected `row`.  This is your problem because this event does not fire it never sets the last clicked row and thus never looks to remove its class. I rewrote the directive for you so that it would work for what you are trying to achieve but it could pretty easily be improved.

```
app.directive('prSystem', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
      require: '^stTable',
      scope: {
        row: '=prSystem'
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
          var mode = attr.stSelectMode || 'single';
          if(scope.row.isSelected) {
              scope.row.isSelected = undefined;
              ctrl.select(scope.row, mode);
          }

        element.bind('click', function () {
          scope.$apply(function () {
            ctrl.select(scope.row, mode);
          });
        });

        scope.$watch('row.isSelected', function (newValue) {
          if (newValue === true) {
            element.addClass('st-selected');
          } else {
            element.removeClass('st-selected');
          }
        });
      }
  }
})
```

Comment: I don't like to have to redefine an existing directive, but I prefer this solution to mine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found a solution:

No more `$watch`, but a `ng-click` on each rows:

```
<tr st-select-row="row" ng-repeat="row in displayCollection" ng-click="selectRow(row)">
```

And I manually unselect all row before selecting the clicked one:

```
scope.selectRow = function (row) {
    for (var i = 0, len = scope.displayCollection.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        scope.displayCollection[i].isSelected = false;
    }
    row.isSelected = true;
    scope.selected = row;
}
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6pykn5hu/6/

If someone has a better solution, I am open to other suggestions :)

Comment: I have used this and to avoid iteration it's good to use index of array and when remove isSelected value. Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uoa9fckr/